# Google Cloud Storage Client API fails in Certificate validation if we pass javax ssl params

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-storage

I have successfully builded and ran a code snippet to upload the document to google cloud storage using the Java API. While integration of Google Sql to our project we have introduced the keystore and truststore params. After the introduction of the store params the upload document API's are failing with Certification related errors.

> Dec 26, 2017 4:00:46 PM com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest execute
>   WARNING: exception thrown while executing request
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>
> Caused by: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Error getting
>   access token for service account:

If we remove the javax ssl params the code is working as expected, Is it because Cloud storage Api's are using the cloud sql ssl certificates to connect to the storage ? If it is the case is there a way to skip checking of certificates in cloud storage API ? Or What is the best way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we had a very similar complex problem and it turned out to be MacAfee Web gateway (MWG) proxy configuration causing this issue. We noticed a strange behavior of the SSL certificate validation where it works from one process and gives an error from another process. It worked from straight command line Java execution but gave an error when we ran the same code through a container. We imported all the certs from accounts.google.com and *.googleapsi.com. We were clue less on what to do.

It looks that MacAfee Web gateway (MWG) proxy white list configuration is based on the client process(exe or script) name. MWG has default configuration to white list all HTTPS URLs for Java.exe process but not for other process (exe) names such as container(odi.exe). Because of this setting in MacAfee Web gateway proxy the command line Java code worked successfully and the same code from container gave error. We also noticed that if there is a proxy issued SSL cert for the HTTPS URL then SSL cert validation worked.